# ISO-8859-1 (True / False)

Tags: email, encoding, encode, iso-8859-1

Is this a true or false statement?

Unicode is a superset of ISO-8859-1 such that the first 256 Unicode characters correspond to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I think you mean: "Is **Unicode** a superset of ISO-8859-1 such that the first 256 Unicode characters correspond to ISO-8859-1?" UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding of Unicode, whose 0x80-0xFF bytes ("continuation bytes") have context-dependent meaning, unrelated to ISO-8859-1 values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The encoding for specification: ISO-8859-1 only consists of ONLY 256
>   encoding. Meaning, there is nothing more than the 256 codes.

True. The encoding uses only eight bits for each character, so there are only 256 possible characters.

> UTF-8 is a superset that has for its first 256 encoding code the same
>   as ISO-8859-1.

Not exactly correct, but essentially true.

The ISO-8859-1 character set is the same as the first 256 characters in the Unicode character set. The UTF-8 encoding is used to encode Unicode characters. As UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding, it uses some codes in the 0-255 range as the start of multi-byte codes. This means that you can't safely decode ISO-8859-1 as UTF-8 or vice versa.

Ref: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Answer (score 2):

The first paragraph of the Wikipedia page[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1) answers this: "[ISO 8859-1] defines the first 256 code point assignments in Unicode[.]"

Comment: Ah, I see now; sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

256 characters : http://htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

I vote **TRUE**