# How to convert Java String into byte[]?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Is there any way to convert Java `String` to a `byte[]` (*not* the boxed `Byte[]`)?

In trying this:

```
System.out.println(response.split("\r\n\r\n")[1]);
System.out.println("******");
System.out.println(response.split("\r\n\r\n")[1].getBytes().toString());
```

and I'm getting separate outputs. Unable to display 1st output as it is a gzip string.

```
<A Gzip String>
******
[B@38ee9f13
```

The second is an address. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I need the result in a `byte[]` to feed it to gzip decompressor, which is as follows.

```
String decompressGZIP(byte[] gzip) throws IOException {
    java.util.zip.Inflater inf = new java.util.zip.Inflater();
    java.io.ByteArrayInputStream bytein = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(gzip);
    java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream gzin = new java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream(bytein);
    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream byteout = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int res = 0;
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    while (res >= 0) {
        res = gzin.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
        if (res > 0) {
            byteout.write(buf, 0, res);
        }
    }
    byte uncompressed[] = byteout.toByteArray();
    return (uncompressed.toString());
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499924/convert-java-string-to-byte-array

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to convert a String to bytearray and back and getting a wrong result. I'll edit it in a while and get back.

Comment: Your problem is that `String.getBytes()` does indeed return a byte array, but your belief that the `toString()` of a byte array will return a useful result is incorrect.

Answer (score 1057, accepted):

The object your method `decompressGZIP()` needs is a `byte[]`.

So the basic, technical answer to the question you have asked is:

```
byte[] b = string.getBytes();
byte[] b = string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
byte[] b = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // Java 7+ only
```

---

However the problem you appear to be wrestling with is that this doesn't display very well. Calling `toString()` will just give you the default `Object.toString()` which is the class name + memory address. In your result `[B@38ee9f13`, the `[B` means `byte[]` and `38ee9f13` is the memory address, separated by an `@`.

For display purposes you can use:

```
Arrays.toString(bytes);
```

But this will just display as a sequence of comma-separated integers, which may or may not be what you want.

To get a readable `String` back from a `byte[]`, use:

```
String string = new String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset);
```

---

The reason the `Charset` version is favoured, is that all `String` objects in Java are stored internally as UTF-16. When converting to a `byte[]` you will get a different breakdown of bytes for the given glyphs of that `String`, depending upon the chosen charset.

Comment: string.getBytes("UTF-8") requires handling an UnsupportedEncodingException, while string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")) does not. Arguing as to which method is "better" I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: `string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` can also be used, and it is the same as `string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`

Comment: I believe `StandardCharsets` is new with Java 7

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698354/where-to-get-utf-8-string-literal-in-java

Comment: I have a problem I use getBytes to convert my string to bytes, but I cannot seems to get back the string from it. I tried .toString()

Comment: Try the constructor `new String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset) `

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got so many upvotes. It may be right, but it's not very helpful ... just a couple of lines of code, most of which the OP already had, and not explaining what difference `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` makes or why it's important.

Comment: @LarsH You make a good point. To be honest, I never expected this answer to become so popular. I have now expanded the answer in order to "deserve" the upvotes. Hopefully it's an improvement.

Comment: In my case it was getBytes("ISO-8859-1");   For ISO Latin Alphabet. Thanks for the answer. This Direct me to the correct path.

Comment: @DinithRukshanKumara  It's worth looking at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643694/iso-8859-1-true-false

Answer (score 65):

```
  String example = "Convert Java String";
  byte[] bytes = example.getBytes();
```

Comment: Beware: [getBytes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) is platform dependent. Better choice is to use [getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: Method getBytes is deprecated now.

Answer (score 18):

Simply:

```
String abc="abcdefghight";

byte[] b = abc.getBytes();
```

Comment: What if `abc` contains non US-ASCII characters, like `"greater than 2³² − 1"` or just binary data (like "�A���b2")?

Comment: this does not work for characters like `�  ` this string has only 5 characters. However when I use  `getBytes()` i got 7 characters.

Comment: Method getBytes is deprecated now.

Answer (score 15):

Try using String.getBytes(). It returns a byte[] representing string data.
Example:

```
String data = "sample data";
byte[] byteData = data.getBytes();
```

Comment: Method getBytes is deprecated now.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `String.getBytes()` which returns the `byte[]` array.

Answer (score 8):

You might wanna try `return new String(byteout.toByteArray(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))`

Comment: Thanks for showing other way around from bytes to String.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late tothe party but thisworks pretty neat (our professor gave it to us)

```
public static byte[] asBytes (String s) {                   
           String tmp;
           byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
           int i;
           for (i = 0; i < s.length() / 2; i++) {
             tmp = s.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2);
             b[i] = (byte)(Integer.parseInt(tmp, 16) & 0xff);
           }
           return b;                                            //return bytes
    }
```

Comment: This decodes hex-encoded byte array. Something very different from what this question is about.

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary to change java as a String parameter. You have to change the c code to receive a String without a pointer and in its code:

```
Bool DmgrGetVersion (String szVersion);

Char NewszVersion [200];
Strcpy (NewszVersion, szVersion.t_str ());
.t_str () applies to builder c ++ 2010
```