# Java - Recover bytes from string

Tags: java, byte

In java,

```
// already set
byte[] bytes = ...;
```

byte array can be cast to string like

```
String s = bytes.toString();
```

**The question is: how can I recover the same "bytes" from "s"?**

the truth is that, the following code is wrong.

```
byte[] byteFromString = x.getBytes();
```

Comment: The answer to your question could depend on the _encoding_ which the string has.  For example, in UTF-8, a character might consist of 4 bytes, but it could also consist of only one byte.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834854/how-to-cast-string-to-byte-array

Comment: Strictly speaking `String s = bytes.toString();` isn't a cast operation

Answer (score 0):

If you just used `bytes.toString()`, then no it's literally impossible.  That gets you a string representing the hash code of the `byte[]`, which is essentially random and bears no relationship to the actual contents of the `byte[]`.

If the `byte[]` actually represented an encoding of a string, like UTF-8, then you can do `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` to convert it to a `String`, and `string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` to convert it back.

Comment: Get! Thanks a lot.