# String to byte array type conversion

Tags: java, android, string, arrays

I want to convert string to byte array like below:

If I have a string:

```
String str = "0x61";
```

I want it as:

```
byte[] byteArray = {0x61};
```

Any idea?

Comment: is the "0x" in the beginning mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you could do -

```
String str = "0x61";
byte[] arr = new byte[] {(byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(2), 16)};
System.out.println(arr[0] == 0x61);
```

Output is

```
true
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you leaving out parts of the information here? The problem you describe can be done with a simple

```
byte[] byteArray = {Byte.decode(str)};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you are trying to achieve. Can you elaborate on your use case?

I believe what you want is

```
str.getBytes();
```

look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18571348/2163130

Answer (score 0):

if your string doesn't have 0x before every digit, then this method will perform the conversion:

```
private byte[] generateByteArray(String byteArrayStr)
    {
        byte[] result = new byte[byteArrayStr.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArrayStr.length(); i += 2)
        {       
            result[i / 2] = (byte)((Character.digit(byteArrayStr.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(byteArrayStr.charAt(i + 1), 16));               
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This method will transform "FF00" into {255, 0}

You will need to make sure that the length of the String is even, since every 2 digits will constitute 1 byte (in hex format).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Convert hex to long
Step 2) Convert long to byte array.

```
String str = "0x61";    
long l = Long.valueOf(str).longValue(); //step 1
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(l).array(); //step 2
```