# Convert Binary String to Binary

Tags: java, string, binary, arrays

How do I convert a String written as Binary, to binary (in byte array)?

If I have a String:

`String binary = "0000"`

I want the binary data to be `0000`.

below is what happens when I set the binary to a byte array (which in turn returns 48, which is ASCII)

`Binary String: 0000
    Binary Byte array: 48
    Binary Byte array: 48
    Binary Byte array: 48
    Binary Byte array: 48`

I'm not good at explaining so hopefully the above example was enough to tell you what I want.

*EDIT:* This is to set the data into a binary file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Java String to byte\[\] array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/convert-java-string-to-byte-array)

Comment: At least @Braj knows what Im talking about. PM 77-1 This is in no possible way a duplicate of Coverting a Java String to a byte[] array. Im aware of how to do that, Im NOT aware however, of how to put the actual input string value and set it as binary.

Comment: OK I got it your point. Let me update it.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer - You seem to be confused about different *represenations* of a value.

Comment: You have to mention that you want **decimal value from binary.**

Comment: I was deducted a point because in what way is this NOT helpful!? This isn't the same thing as `byte[] b = str.getBytes();`!!!

Comment: @Braj but its the other way around. I want decimal value TO binary... allow me to edit the post...

Comment: I was confused with `0000` in what format it is 1. decimal 2. binary?

Comment: have a look at my post to make it vice-versa.

Comment: If you are dealing with Java strings, 48 is not ASCII, it's a Unicode/UTF-16 code-unit. In this case, the single code-unit needed for the U+0030 codepoint ([DIGIT ZERO](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/30/index.htm)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt("000",2))); // gives 0
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt("010",2))); // gives 10
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt("100",2))); // gives 100
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! And well, probably the only place too that has this code...

Comment: So is this any different than just stripping leading 0's off the input string, without doing any binary/decimal conversions?  (Assuming the input is valid.)

Comment: Well not having to strip anything, this is more efficient. Plus Strings are NOT my forte.

Answer (score 1):

> Convert into Decimal from Binary

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("1010",2).toString()); // 10 decimal
```

> Convert into Binary/Octal/Hex from Decimal

You can use [BigInteger#toString(radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29) method to get value in any radix.

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("10").toString(2));  // 1010  binary
System.out.println(new BigInteger("10").toString(8));  // 12    octal
System.out.println(new BigInteger("10").toString(16)); // a     hexadecimal
```

---

Let me explain you a bit more how it works with different base

(10)<sub>10</sub> = (1010)<sub>2</sub>

(10)<sub>10</sub> = (12)<sub>8</sub>

(10)<sub>10</sub> = (a)<sub>16</sub>

Comment: ehm I already tried that, I dont want ASCII, I want the  String to be the actual binary data in my file, otherwise I end up with 48 48 48 48 WHICH ISNT BINARY.

Comment: This is no doubt helpful, `System.out.println(newBigInteger(int radix).toString(2));` however this is a String input that I want to write as text and then put into a new binary file. Not something confusing for the consumer of the software I want to make.

Comment: have a look at updated post with base value. It's simple mathematics.

Comment: Yeah, but I mean the highest value you can get with a 4-bit binary value is 256. Im talking ALLLLLL binary here. Nothing really to do with decimals at all. This is binary in String form that I want to write to a binary file. And dang it is hard for me to explain :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

```
int i = Integer.valueOf(binary, 2); // ie base 2
```

This call expects the input to be a string of 0 and 1 chars.

Then if you want an array of bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = new ByteBuffer().putInt(i).compact().array();
```

Comment: This will give 4 for the input "100".

Comment: I want the binary data to be 0000. what does it mean. The value is in decimal and OP wants to convert it into binary.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos yes - I think hhat's what OP wants, but the question is a bit unclear - you could well be right that OP wants a different result.

Comment: @Braj that's not how I read the question: there are only 0 chars in his example input, so we can't be sure.

Comment: yes that's why I don't want to delete my post to make it helpful for others.

Comment: Well to put it simply, 0000 is a value of 0. 1111 is a value of 256. Im showing 0000 as a string but in decimal form, not binary form. I mean the String says its decimal like you could have 0002 and it would be 2 but I want it to be parsed and written as the binary value of 0000. If the String was 1111 I would want the value to be 1111 (in binary).

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer Why is `1111` a value of 256?

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer what will be value of 1111 in binary? First tell me in what base it is?

Comment: 1111 is the binary value for the decimal 256.

Comment: @Braj does base even matter? 1111 is binary, which is the integer value 256. I don't see what the confusion is... really.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer You may want to check your math.

Comment: I never wanted to get into math!!! I just wanted a way to put binary in string form, into a binary file!!!

Comment: How on earth can 1111 be 256? 1111 is 15 decimal. 11111111 is 255. Please explain what the conversion is. (btw, you probably shouldn't call your string variable `binary` if it's decimal)

Answer (score 1):

[JBBP framework](https://code.google.com/p/java-binary-block-parser/) has in utils a special method to convert a string contains a binary defined data into byte array

```
 byte [] converted = JBBPUtils.str2bin("00000000");
```