# convert a string got from Jsonobject to Byte[];

Tags: android

I am transmitting a PDF in Bytearray from WEB API,

I am getting the response as follows

```
 {"document":"JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48\/TDQoNCjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZw0KL091dGxpbmVzIDIgMCBSDQovUGFnZXMgMyAwIFINCj4+DQplbmRvYmoNCg0KMiAwIG9iag0KPDwNCi9UeXBlIC9PdXRsaW5lcw0KL0NvdW50IDANCj4+DQplbmRvYmoNCg0KMyAwIG9iag0KPDwNCi9UeXBlIC"}
```

I want to convert that string to Byte array[] for rendering the PDF;

Please Help me with problem;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Java String into byte\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the Bytearray from JSON using

```
  pdfbytes =   Base64.decode(response.getString("document"), Base64.DEFAULT) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String json = "{\"document\":\"JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48\/TDQoNCjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZw0KL091dGxpbmVzIDIgMCBSDQovUGFnZXMgMyAwIFINCj4+DQplbmRvYmoNCg0KMiAwIG9iag0KPDwNCi9UeXBlIC9PdXRsaW5lcw0KL0NvdW50IDANCj4+DQplbmRvYmoNCg0KMyAwIG9iag0KPDwNCi9UeXBlIC\"}";

JSONObject json_object = new JSONObject(json);

byte[] b = json_object.getString("document").getBytes();
//or
byte[] b = json_object.getString("document").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as :

```
byte[] byte = yourstring.getBytes();
byte[] byte = yourstring.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: But When I convert the response into string wont i loose data

Comment: din't get you? please explain properly

Answer (score 0):

```
    String data = "sample text";
    byte[] b = data.getBytes();
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, `code` only answers are highly discouraged!

Answer (score 0):

Use getBytes() method in string

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()