# Compress object to a string or a hash and and viceversa?

Tags: java, json, string

I am trying to do this...

I have a big object that I need to send from the backend to the view and from that view to other backend as parameter in a GET post. So, since I cannot send all the object, I thought about make it a very small string or a number, and for this I tried doing this.

First I converted the object to `JSON`, using `JSONObject`,but due the special characters I cannot take it as a normal string (it has many `", /, {},....`) so, I thought make it a byte, but I am not sure if is a correct approach, any idea how to do this?

Or something similar to have my object in an acceptable GET parameter for the URL.

So far I only have this code.

```
byte[] foo = new JSONObject(myObject).toString().getBytes();
String bar = foo.toString();
```

But dont know who to parse it back to byte and have not even tried to parse it back to JSON, any idea?

I am using spring and I dont have gson or jackson for convert to json an object.

Comment: The code you have given will not "work fine" - you'll end with a string such as `[B@abcdef12`. It sounds to me like you're only interested in string to `byte[]` conversions, and JSON is entirely irrelevant for that part. But "I  have a json string, I want to make it a very small string (without special characters)." sounds like you want compression. Do you understand that you won't always be able to compress it? You've used `hash` in your tags, but not mentioned anything about a hash in your body... but hashing isn't reversible. It's hard to tell what you want, really...

Comment: I actually have an object, I need to send it between pages (I cannot modify so much code) so, I thought about send it as a small string or hashnumber, but the hash is not possible to get it back... Is there any way I compress my object to a small string or something like that?

Comment: You probably want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte). I would typically close as duplicate, but you're involving `JSONObject`, but I don't understand why. Please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks, Ive updated my question to make it more exact and clear

Comment: Any character can be sent as a GET parameter. It just needs to be properly URL-encoded. Otherwise, you couldn't use google to search for any term containing a / or a {, for example. That said, the fact that you're sending an entire object as parameter is an indication that you should probably use a POST or a PUT rather than a GET.

Comment: I wonder why the downvotes..