# Sending a String via Serial COMM

Tags: java, string, serial-port, byte

I'm developing a system with Gemalto BG5ST (a java modem).
I need to send a string sent via http GET request to the Serial Port. 
This string is stored, but the problem is that I need the data to be int or byte in order to write in the Outputstream.

Is there anyway to go around this?

```
OutputStream outStream = null;
  String strCOM = "comm:COM0;blocking=off;baudrate=115200";//autocts=off;autorts=off
  CommConnection commConn = (CommConnection)Connector.open(strCOM)
  inStream  = commConn.openInputStream();
  outStream = commConn.openOutputStream();
```

Working with IDE 1.3 due to modem restrictions.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte

Comment: That answer only works on 1.7 IDE, and I need it on 1.3 
:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

str.getBytes() - 1.1 version, used default charset

str.getBytes("UTF-8") - 1.1 version

Answer (score 0):

I did this to solve the issue.

```
byte[] data = v1.getBytes();
int j;
for (j=0;j<data.length;j++)
{
    outStream.write(data[j]);
    System.out.println(data[j]);
}
```

Thanks guys.