# WS response body as bytes

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am using `WS` to call distant api. The answer is formatted as a byte array. How do I parse the body of a `WSResponse` as a byte array ? I don't want to use the boilerplate `getStream`.

```
val holder: WSRequestHolder = WS.url(url)
  .withRequestTimeout(requestTimeout)
  .withHeaders(HeaderNames.ACCEPT -> ContentTypes.BINARY)
holder.get() map { response => response.status match {
  case 200 => response.bodyAsBytes // I am looking for the bodyAsBytes function
}}
```

Comment: `bodyAsBytes` exists as of Play 2.4.x

Comment: @MichaelZajac I am using play `2.3.9` :(

Answer (score 1):

Get the body of the response in string format and then convert it into bytes with appropriate format

```
response.body.toString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

Also look at [Convert string to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte)