# Java - Reverse new String from charset encoding into bytes

Tags: java, arrays, character-encoding

Okay so let's say I read a file and obtain all its bytes, byte[].

```
byte[] fileBytes = whatever;
```

(Let's pretend whatever is me reading the bytes)

Now let's say I made a string out of it with the OS's default charset,

```
String s = new String(fileBytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

In my case the OS's default charset is windows-1252.

Right now because we read the file through the default charset, s.getBytes() is different from fileBytes.

How could we reverse the String s knowing the default charset back into the original fileBytes?

I appreciate all help, thanks! :)

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with reversing the byte array and the converting to a string using whatever encoding you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Java String into byte\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte)

Comment: Is this an endian issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you can do it vice versa.

```
byte[] fileBytes = whatever;
String s = new String(fileBytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

You can reverse it by doing the following.

```
byte[] reversedFileBytes = s.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
```