# How to initialise byte format like "[B@139a55" for converting into text in java?

Tags: java

Here is some text `"Hi hello"` if I convert it to bytes  it will print `"[B@139a55"` , Without giving any string directly with this byte `"[B@139a55"`

can I convert a byte[] to a string in Java ??

```
byte[] bytes = aBuffer.getBytes(); 
System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes.toString());
String s = new String(bytes); 
System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + s);
```

Comment: Note: `String` is a sequence of `char`, not `byte`.

Comment: You will find a similar question and answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte

Comment: `[B@139a55` is not a byte sequence. Insteads, it's simply the debug output for byte arrays. It basically means: the byte array at address 139a55.

Comment: You are not outputting it right. Show your code.

Comment: byte[] bytes = aBuffer.getBytes();

         
          System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes.toString());String s = new String(bytes);
          System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + s);

Comment: @Codo  Reverse engineering Is that possible to get text back with that address.

Comment: @AndyTurner For getting byte format  I am using a string  " byte[] bytes = aBuffer.getBytes();"  Here is that aBuffer is string.

Comment: @Fildor I want to output that text

Comment: @Codo note the number is a generated 31-bit hashCode not an address (which could be 64-bit) and it doesn't change as the byte[] is moved around in memory.

Comment: @jerry the number is a randomly generated hashCode which has no information you can use to recreate the original contents of the `byte[]`.

Comment: there is no such thing as `pointer` in Java, so there is no such thing as 'address' as well. What you see in the output is a default implementation of `toString()` method in `java.lang.Object`

Comment: @PeterLawrey the string is assigned to that byte ,once we give that byte[] the string "hi hello" is printed ,likewise is there possible to give just the byte[] to get text.how we recreate the original content of that byte[]??

Comment: @jerry " the string is assigned to that byte" - no it is not. You don't print what you think you are printing.

Answer (score 2):

`[72, 105, 32, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111]` - Is it what you'd like to see out of that string `Hi Hello` ?

Then do that:

```
    String str = "Hi hello";

    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();

    // convert
    Byte[] bytesWrap = new Byte[bytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytesWrap[i] = bytes[i];
    }
    String bytesStr = Arrays.asList(bytesWrap).toString();
    //print result
    System.out.println("bytes in \"" + str + "\":" + bytesStr);
```

UPDATED: Explanation: 
default implementation of java.util.List.toString() produces string like `[ element.toString(),element.toString() ...]`
Then there is a `java.utils.Arrays` utilitiy which can convert array to list, but... elements must be Objects, not primitives.

So, steps are
1.  convert from `byte[]` to corresponding Object wrapper `Byte[]` 
2.  convert `Byte[]` to List 
3. Use List.toString()

Of course it is just a demonstration how to use List to simply print Array which is good for objects. 
For that particular case with primitives there is more simple code.

```
    String str = "Hi hello";

    StringBuilder bytesStrBuilder =new StringBuilder("[ ");
    for (byte bt:str.getBytes()) {
        bytesStrBuilder.append(bt).append(" ");
    }       
    String bytesStr = bytesStrBuilder.append("]").toString();

    System.out.println("bytes in \"" + str + "\":" + bytesStr);
```

Comment: You should explain the subtlety of this wrap. And I don't see the point of using `asList` a second time

Comment: @AxelH - you are right - my bad. :-)

Comment: I like the idea, but you seems to have forget a simpler solution, check the answer I have write ;)

Comment: @AxelH - sure `Arrays.toString()` is better. It was early morning :-) and it was new to me that Arrays.asList() does not take `byte[]`, or any other primitive arrays. Since usually I have no primitive arrays I use asList() often enough.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure of what you asked, but to convert a Byte[] into the Sting, simply use the `String(byte[])` constructor.

```
String s = new String("foo bar".getBytes());`
```

If you want to print each bytes of a String, Vadim solution is correct but there is a much shorter version. I used his output line to keep the format

```
byte[] bytes = "Hi hello".getBytes();
System.out.println("bytes in \"" + new String(bytes) + "\":" + Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

The idea is the same but the `Arrays.toString` method will do it for you since it accept a `byte[]`, it will iterate through it and generate a String using a `StringBuilder`.