# android - How to convert String to same byte[] value in java

Tags: java, android, byte

My input is "[B@ec3c95b"

String example ="[B@ec3c95b";

I want to make it same as output "[B@ec3c95b" in byte array type.

Comment: It sounds to me like someone's called `toString()` on a `byte[]` and assumed the result is useful - it's not. Please give more context, so we can help figure out what the root of the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Java String into byte\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want to convert a String in a byte array.

For that, you can use the `getBytes()` function to convert your String :

```
String input = "[B@ec3c95b";
byte[] output = input.getBytes();
```

Comment: I don't see the difference. It is being stored in a byte array, what the user wanted.

Comment: I tried this way and found that getBytes was just generate a byte for the input data. there are not same output.

Comment: I really don't undersant what you want. Can you be more explicit please ?