# how to converting byte array to string?

Tags: android, arrays, string

I have a byte array and i want to convert it to arabic string in android.

```
     byte[] data = new byte[] {(byte)79,(byte)144,(byte)2,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)166,(byte)6,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)128,(byte)47,(byte)60,(byte)70,(byte)79,(byte)78,(byte)84,(byte)32,(byte)67,(byte)79,(byte)76,(byte)79,(byte)82,(byte)61,(byte)34,(byte)35,(byte)57,(byte)48,(byte)57,(byte)48,(byte)57,(byte)48,(byte)34,(byte)62,(byte)199,(byte)157,(byte)32,(byte)98,(byte)97,(byte)110,(byte)194,(byte)180,(byte)64,(byte)32,(byte)8,(byte)192,(byte)100,(byte)199,(byte)157,(byte)110,(byte)60,(byte)47,(byte)198,(byte)8,(byte)62,(byte)47,(byte)60,(byte)47,(byte)112,(byte)62,(byte)174,(byte)11,(byte)48,(byte)48,(byte)55,(byte)48,(byte)48,(byte)184,(byte)118,(byte)116,(byte)46,(byte)60,(byte)47,(byte)102,(byte)111,(byte)110,(byte)116,(byte)62,(byte)10,(byte)9,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)128,(byte)160,(byte)112,(byte)32,(byte)97,(byte)108,(byte)105,(byte)103,(byte)110,(byte)61,(byte)114,(byte)105,(byte)103,(byte)104,(byte)116,(byte)32,(byte)100,(byte)105,(byte)114,(byte)61,(byte)114,(byte)116,(byte)108,(byte)62,(byte)60,(byte)70,(byte)8,(byte)32,(byte)99,(byte)111,(byte)108,(byte)111,(byte)64,(byte)101,(byte)32,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)128,(byte)100,(byte)62,(byte)226,(byte)151,(byte)143,(byte)82,(byte)13,(byte)32,(byte)216,(byte)177,(byte)217,(byte)135,(byte)216,(byte)167,(byte)32,(byte)218,(byte)169,(byte)216,(byte)177,(byte)216,(byte)175,(byte)217,(byte)134,(byte)216,(byte)140,(byte)32,(byte)216,(byte)175,(byte)216,(byte)179,(byte)216,(byte)170,(byte)17,(byte)128,(byte)85,(byte)140,(byte)134,(byte)4,(byte)180,(byte)219,(byte)140,(byte)18,(byte)5,(byte)217,(byte)133,(byte)216,(byte)170,(byte)217,(byte)136,(byte)217,(byte)130,(byte)217,(byte)129,(byte)166,(byte)10,(byte)72,(byte)132,(byte)170,(byte)14,(byte)181,(byte)57,(byte)1,(byte)129,(byte)44,(byte)184,(byte)216,(byte)177,(byte)26,(byte)6,(byte)234,(byte)37,(byte)108,(byte)101,(byte)102,(byte)177,(byte)0,(byte)1,(byte)134,(byte)142,(byte)37,(byte)108,(byte)116,(byte)114,(byte)170,(byte)37,(byte)78,(byte)52,(byte)99,(byte)69,(byte)3,(byte)100,(byte)111,(byte)32,(byte)110,(byte)111,(byte)116,(byte)32,(byte)97,(byte)17,(byte)4,(byte)100,(byte)111,(byte)110,(byte)32,(byte)104,(byte)111,(byte)112,(byte)101,(byte)131,(byte)149,(byte)112,(byte)0,(byte)198,(byte)18,(byte)97,(byte)48,(byte)52,(byte)49,(byte)192,(byte)97,(byte)12,(byte)145,(byte)34,(byte)62,(byte)216,(byte)167,(byte)217,(byte)133,(byte)198,(byte)48,(byte)149,(byte)3,(byte)141,(byte)3,(byte)216,(byte)167,(byte)216,(byte)178,(byte)86,(byte)55,(byte)145,(byte)2,(byte)175,(byte)217,(byte)135,(byte)79,(byte)157,(byte)0,(byte)3,(byte)144,(byte)81,(byte)0,(byte)116,(byte)104,(byte)101,(byte)121,(byte)86,(byte)40,(byte)101,(byte)100,(byte)32,(byte)60,(byte)105,(byte)114,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)3,(byte)160,(byte)32,(byte)97,(byte)116,(byte)116,(byte)101,(byte)109,(byte)112,(byte)116,(byte)32,(byte)116,(byte)111,(byte)32,(byte)101,(byte)115,(byte)99,(byte)97,(byte)131,(byte)28,(byte)91,(byte)0,(byte)161,(byte)2,(byte)218,(byte)169,(byte)217,(byte)136,(byte)216,(byte)180,(byte)216,(byte)180,(byte)32,(byte)216,(byte)168,(byte)70,(byte)47,(byte)219,(byte)93,(byte)70,(byte)131,(byte)196,(byte)181,(byte)5,(byte)129,(byte)70,(byte)2,(byte)101,(byte)5,(byte)62,(byte)104,(byte)175,(byte)131,(byte)157,(byte)1,(byte)1,(byte)217,(byte)130,(byte)165,(byte)4,(byte)37,(byte)7,(byte)175,(byte)216,(byte)176,(byte)133,(byte)1,(byte)180,(byte)169,(byte)7,(byte)74,(byte)115,(byte)170,(byte)216,(byte)177,(byte)218,(byte)169,(byte)3,(byte)155,(byte)227,(byte)0,(byte)104,(byte)101,(byte)162,(byte)72,(byte)104,(byte)105,(byte)115,(byte)132,(byte)32,(byte)1,(byte)8,(byte)232,(byte)109,(byte)112,(byte)97,(byte)110,(byte)105,(byte)77,(byte)7,(byte)105,(byte)110,(byte)198,(byte)76,(byte)32,(byte)109,(byte)105,(byte)100,(byte)100,(byte)108,(byte)101,(byte)32,(byte)111,(byte)102,(byte)138,(byte)3,(byte)106,(byte)111,(byte)117,(byte)114,(byte)110,(byte)101,(byte)121,(byte)3,(byte)155,(byte)154,(byte)0,(byte)175,(byte)105,(byte)4,(byte)205,(byte)4,(byte)192,(byte)225,(byte)3,(byte)194,(byte)179,(byte)216,(byte)183,(byte)32,(byte)216,(byte)179,(byte)6,(byte)75,(byte)161,(byte)4,(byte)10,(byte)4,(byte)170,(byte)32,(byte)216,(byte)174,(byte)36,(byte)86,(byte)129,(byte)166,(byte)53,(byte)3,(byte)30,(byte)157,(byte)1,(byte)238,(byte)21,(byte)179,(byte)217,(byte)132,(byte)219,(byte)140,(byte)217,(byte)133,(byte)131,(byte)162,(byte)152,(byte)0,(byte)109,(byte)115,(byte)101,(byte)108,(byte)105,(byte)4,(byte)0,(byte)17,(byte)158,(byte)129,(byte)111,(byte)32,(byte)108,(byte)101,(byte)99,(byte)104,(byte)101,(byte)114,(byte)131,(byte)155,(byte)140,(byte)0,(byte)167,(byte)217,(byte)136,(byte)219,(byte)85,(byte)0,(byte)216,(byte)180,(byte)217,(byte)135,(byte)100,(byte)10,(byte)147,(byte)131,(byte)159,(byte)135,(byte)0,(byte)143,(byte)36,(byte)2,(byte)219,(byte)140,(byte)81,(byte)10,(byte)245,(byte)8,(byte)168,(byte)219,(byte)140,(byte)226,(byte)128,(byte)140,(byte)60,(byte)183,(byte)67,(byte)128,(byte)216,(byte)168,(byte)134,(byte)167,(byte)97,(byte)6,(byte)198,(byte)177,(byte)241,(byte)10,(byte)219,(byte)140,(byte)3,(byte)26,(byte)46,(byte)0,(byte)202,(byte)165,(byte)105,(byte)1,(byte)167,(byte)177,(byte)10,(byte)121,(byte)1,(byte)180,(byte)217,(byte)2,(byte)198,(byte)123,(byte)40,(byte)216,(byte)185,(byte)217,(byte)129,(byte)131,(byte)150,(byte)181,(byte)0,(byte)99,(byte)104,(byte)105,(byte)108,(byte)100,(byte)105,(byte)115,(byte)104,(byte)47,(byte)24,(byte)0,(byte)136,(byte)86,(byte)92,(byte)3,(byte)27,(byte)174,(byte)0,(byte)50,(byte)34,(byte)142,(byte)237,(byte)175,(byte)57,(byte)5,(byte)167,(byte)217,(byte)134,(byte)217,(byte)135,(byte)3,(byte)144,(byte)43,(byte)0,(byte)131,(byte)143,(byte)90,(byte)0,(byte)98,(byte)108,(byte)97,(byte)99,(byte)107,(byte)34,(byte)32,(byte)115,(byte)116,(byte)121,(byte)108,(byte)101,(byte)61,(byte)34,(byte)134,(byte)6,(byte)45,(byte)119,(byte)101,(byte)1,(byte)2,(byte)124,(byte)128,(byte)70,(byte)17,(byte)58,(byte)98,(byte)111,(byte)108,(byte)100,(byte)34,(byte)62,(byte)42,(byte)86,(byte)49,(byte)105,(byte)110,(byte)103,(byte)32,(byte)115,(byte)104,(byte)105,(byte)112,(byte)3,(byte)155,(byte)102,(byte)0,(byte)142,(byte)198,(byte)197,(byte)6,(byte)201,(byte)8,(byte)82,(byte)17,(byte)60,(byte)47,(byte)112,(byte)62};

String head2=new String(data);
```

but i get this string :

> O�����������������/ǝ ban´@
>   �dǝn/
>
> �00700�vt.     ������p align=right dir=rtl>●R  رها کردن، دست�U���یمتوقف�
>   H���9�,�ر�%lef�����%ltr�%N4cEdo not adon
>   hope��p���a041�a�">ام�0��ازV7��هO����Q��theyV(ed h���ق�%�ذ���Js�رک����he�Hhis� �mpaniMin�L
>   middle of�journey�����i���³ط سK� �
>   خ$V��5���لیم�����mseli����o lecher������و�U��شهd �������$یQ
>   ��ی‌<�C�ب��aƱ� ی.��ʥi��
>   y���{(عف�����childish/���V\���2"��9�نه�+����Z��black"
>   style="�-we|�F:bold">*V1ing ship�f������R

by the way my string contains html tag too.
so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your byte array is using `UTF-8` as it's default charset (for more [read here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])).

try changing to something like this:

```
byte[] data == // getData();
String str = new String(data, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here: [How to convert Java String into byte[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte)

"[A]ll String objects in Java are stored internally as UTF-16. When converting to a byte[] you will get a different breakdown of bytes for the given glyphs of that String, depending upon the chosen charset."

So you have to specify a charset as well: `String string = new String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset);`

For example UTF-16 or ASCII

Comment: What Charset did you convert the byte array from?

Comment: it was stored in a sqlite db as blob data and i want to convert it to string.i dont know what was the Charset.