# How can I modify this method that converts bytes to String so that it can convert the String to bytes?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

```
private static String bytesToString(byte[] encrypted) {
    //above method converts bytes to string
    String test = "";

    for (byte b : encrypted) {
        test += Byte.toString(b);
    }

    return test;
}
```

I have this method that converts bytes to String. How can I modify it so that it can convert the String to bytes?

Comment: Your String ( test ) has a method named .getBytes() to convert it to bytes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Java String into byte\[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte)

Comment: Are you sure this is possible?
Lets say you got "Alex" as string.. this gives array {65,108,101,120}.
The method you got will give a string 6510801120. Forgetting java... how could you know hot to make this back to arrray?
{65 10 80 11 20} and {65,108,101,120} are both valid ..
Could you use a separater when concatenating the test string?

Comment: What should the bytes contain - an ASCII representation of each character?

Comment: Agreeing with @kumesana and erickson, you'd want a reversible scheme. Base64 and two-digit hexadecimal are typical; as are just letting a byte array be a byte array—that's what encryption/decryption algorithms operate on.

Answer (score 3):

That is impossible with the conversion you're doing.

Let's imagine the bytes you're "converting" are as so:

```
new byte[] {1, 0}
```

That's two bytes, and the resulting String is

```
"10"
```

Now let's imagine the bytes are as so:

```
new byte[] {10}
```

That's one byte, and the resulting String is

```
"10"
```

So, two different sequences of bytes can produce the same String "10". It is therefore impossible to decide whether String "10" should be converted back as `{1, 0}` or `{10}` or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Your "modification" should be to use base-64 to *encode and* decode the byte array:

```
private static String bytesToString(byte[] encrypted) {
    return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
}

private static byte[] stringToBytes(String encrypted) {
    return Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(encrypted);
}
```

This will allow you to unambiguously encode any byte array, store and transmit it as text using only 7-bit, US-ASCII characters, then recover the original data.

Answer (score -2):

You can directly use String constructor.

```
String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

look at the documentation [string constructor with bytecode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Doesn't account for OP's "conversion" method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte