# How to convert byte that are in a file to object in java?

Tags: java

I have a hadoop job for which its final output is the following

```
String myKey = "myKey";
context.write(myKey, myObjectWritable.toByteArray());
```

My output file look like the following

```
myKey/t00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

my question is how do I convert the bytes in string to a `byte[]` since the file is consist of string and bytes that is written as string.

```
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my_map_reduce_file"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] x = line.split("\t");

            // how do I convert x[1] to byte[]

       }
```

Comment: The `String` class has a `getBytes()` methd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Java String into byte\[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte)

Comment: If you write the file as binary (non-string), read the file as a binary(non-binary).  the InputStream and OutputStream classes let you read() and write() bytes.  All that said, if the data is actually a string, use TextReader and TextWriter and let the built-in behavior work for you

Answer (score 0):

To read you should revert the write process. If you invented writing yourself - do reading yourself. Otherwise consider `ObjectOutputStream` for writing, `ObjectInputStream` for reading and the whole [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) protocol.

Example for writing

```java
        try(ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))){
            stream.writeObject("Key");
            stream.writeObject("Value");
            stream.flush();
        }
```

and for corresponding reading

```java
        try(ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))){
            String key = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
            String value = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
        }
```

These guys will do all the job for any object, whos class implements `Serializable`, like HashMap and most of the util things you mostly use.

Answer (score 0):

```
String mykey = "myKey";
byte[] mykey_byte_array = mykey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
System.out.println("contents of byte array " + Arrays.toString(mykey_byte_array));
```